# jQuery .css() append or overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When appending the .css() function in jQuery 1.4.4 will the .css() override each of the preceding css, or will it append it?

e.g.

```
$('.GhostIcon').css('opacity', '0.25').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=25)').css('-khtml-opacity', '0.25').css('-moz-opacity', '0.25');
```

And secondly, does this have the same behaviour?

```
$('.GhostIcon').css('opacity', '0.25');
$('.GhostIcon').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=25)');
$('.GhostIcon').css('-khtml-opacity', '0.25');
$('.GhostIcon').css('-moz-opacity', '0.25');
```

Comment: You can chain your function calls, but there's a better shortcut for css, use an object: `$('.GhostIcon').css({'opacity':'0.25', 'filter':'alpha(opacity=25)',...});`

Comment: you may also want to consider adding and removing classes rather than putting css directly on the element, as it will be easier to manage in the future, for example, if you decide that the opacity level needs to change

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting a CSS property on an element will not remove all the other properties it might already have. So yes, it's cumulative. Of course setting a property that's already set will change the value, since you can't have the same property twice.

Edit: Also, you only need to set opacity. jQuery will take care of setting things for lesser browsers.

Comment: "Setting a CSS property on an element will not remove all the other properties" - This is not necessarily true, if CSS is set in another framework, such as angular, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

These styles are applied so that it will work cross browser way. Also you can append the CSS in a single go

```
$('.GhostIcon').css({'opacity': '0.25', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity=25)', '-khtml-opacity': '0.25', '-moz-opacity': '0.25'});
```

Comment: Thanks rahul. This saves a lot of time!!

Answer (score 1):

@JD , if it same value , it will definetly overwrite , if not there it will appened