# How to change background color and set margin on MetisMenu dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to make a dropdown menu using MetisMenu https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu.

Here is what I have until now (it is an animated .gif).

[image]

As you can see there, when I hover the selected dropdown menu a blue background appeared. How can I remove this? Is this a Bootstrap or MetisMenu problem?

Another thing is how can I make so that an opened dropdown menu `aria-expanded="true"` will have the same appearances when it is closed `aria-expanded="false"`?

Here (check menu 2.3) is what I have when the dropdown menu opens.

[image]

Here (check menu 2.3) is what I want, BUT this is when the dropdown menu closes.

[image]

I want so that when close or open the dropdown menu retain the exact same style like when it is closed.

Here are my codes.

```
.container-fluid, .row{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.ntg-container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.ntg-container-fill{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
    padding-left: 1rem !important;
    padding-right: 1rem !important;
    padding-top: 65px !important;
}
.ntg-div-background{
    background: #F8F8F8;
}
body, html{
    background: #222034 !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
li, ul{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.list-group-item{
    color: #000000;
}
li.list-group-item.active{
    background: #F8F8F8;
    margin: 0;
}
li.hover{
    background: red;
}
<ul class="list-group metismenu" id="menu">
    <li class="active list-group-item">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="true">Menu 1.</a>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Menu 1.1.</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Menu 1.2.</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Menu 1.3.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group list-group-item">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Menu 2.1.</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Menu 2.2.</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="#" aria-expanded="true">Menu 2.3.</a>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Menu 2.3.1.</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Menu 2.3.2.</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Menu 2.3.3.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would be extremely happy if someone knows how to solve these 2 problems of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this you can change by calling the **particular ID** for the **tag** which you are **trying to change**

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('foo').style.cssText = 'background-color: red; color: white; font-size: 44px';
}
```

Comment: Ooo. Thank you I used ID instead of a class and it is working, further I tried to change `background: red;` into `background: red !important;`.

Comment: check the below linck which can be useful for u in further cases "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363763/jquery-css-append-or-overwrite"